# Parsing output of svn list command - Cannot get attribute

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml

I am using the saved output of :

```
svn list -R --xml directory
```

As input to a python script, my current code using python 2.6.5:

```
import os
import os.path
import sys
import lxml.etree

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    in_filename = str(sys.argv[1])
    if os.path.isfile (in_filename):
        for ent in lxml.etree.parse (in_filename).iter ('entry'):
            get = ent.xpath
            if ent.get ("kind") == "file":
                log_filename = get ('string(name)')
                log_revision = get ('string(revision)') # This needs Fixing!
                log_date = get ('string(commit/date)')
                print('{0},{1},{2}'.format(log_revision,log_date[:10],log_filename))
```

I cannot extract the `revision="1581"` attribute (just the `1581` is what i need) from the entry, where an entry looks like this:

```
<entry kind="file">
  <name>path/file.c</name>
  <size>3973</size>
  <commit revision="1581">
    <author>user</author>
    <date>2012-09-06T15:40:13.396582Z</date>
  </commit>
</entry>
```

I can get everything else easily enough, just not seeing how to get an attribute that is not at the top level of an entry.

Thanks (and apologies if this is a noob question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revision is an attribute of the commit element, so the correct xpath syntax is `commit/@revision`, so:

```
import os
import os.path
import sys
import lxml.etree

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    in_filename = str(sys.argv[1])
    if os.path.isfile (in_filename):
        for ent in lxml.etree.parse (in_filename).iter ('entry'):
            get = ent.xpath
            if ent.get ("kind") == "file":
                log_filename = get ('string(name)')
                log_revision = get('string(commit/@revision)') # Fixed ;)
                log_date = get ('string(commit/date)')
                print('{0},{1},{2}'.format(log_revision,log_date[:10],log_filename))
```

Comment: Excellent! - Is there a reference for the xpath syntax ?

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
log_revision = ent.find('commit').get("revision")
```